# URL Hack and special characters

Tags: urlhacking

I have a URL hack that I am working on. All works well except when a special character, such as an '&', is in the Account name or Contact name that is being passed from the Contact object to the Opportunity object. Here is my URL:

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Opportunity&retURL=%2F{!Contact.Id}&save_new_url=%2F006%2Fe%3FCF00Nj0000009cvLX%3D%27{!Contact.Name}%27%26CF00Nj0000009cvLX_lkid%3D{!Contact.Id}%26retURL=%2F{!Contact.Id}%26opp3%3D%27{!Account.Name}+{!TODAY()}%27%26accid%3D{!Account.Id}%26ent%3DOpportunity
```

Is there a way to get this to work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the URLENCODE Function

`{!URLENCODE(Account.Name)}`